# Google Map custom Marker image with picasso, refresh twice to show image

Tags: android, google-maps, google-maps-api-3, picasso

In my google maps for android app, I am using picasso to show a custom marker image, I have to refresh the activity twice to get it to show the custom image for the marker.  The first time shows the default marker, then when I refresh it shows the custom marker. how can I get it to show the custom marker the first time?

Main Activity:

```
myMarker = mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(new LatLng(Double.parseDouble(latitude), Double.parseDouble(longitude))).title(profile_icon).snippet());
PicassoMarker marker = new PicassoMarker(myMarker);
Picasso.with(MainActivity.this).load(icon_url).into(marker);
```

PicassoMarker:

```
public class PicassoMarker implements Target {
Marker mMarker;

PicassoMarker(Marker marker) {
    mMarker = marker;
}

@Override
public int hashCode() {
    return mMarker.hashCode();
}

@Override
public boolean equals(Object o) {
    if(o instanceof PicassoMarker) {
        Marker marker = ((PicassoMarker) o).mMarker;
        return mMarker.equals(marker);
    } else {
        return false;
    }
}

@Override
public void onBitmapLoaded(Bitmap bitmap, Picasso.LoadedFrom from) {
    mMarker.setIcon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.fromBitmap(bitmap));

}

@Override
public void onBitmapFailed(Drawable errorDrawable) {
}

@Override
public void onPrepareLoad(Drawable placeHolderDrawable) {

}
}
```

Comment: Any solution found for this?